# Access a network machine with ip address but not with the name?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, dhcp

In the File Explorer in can access the machine with ip address \10.xxx.xx.xx but cant access it at \hostname. I have two machines that have this issue.
Both the machines are on LAN. They have static ip. Machine1 is running Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2. Machine 2 is running Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition x64 Service Pack 1.
DNS\DHCP Server is on  Windows Server Standard( I am guessing it is 2008)[image]
Standard Edition, Machine2 The ip is reserved in DHCP.

Please no PowerShell unless they work on Powershell 1.0. We are running on archaic OS.

I have done the following for both the machines:

- ping works
- pingpath 0packets lost
- SMB.1 is active on client and on host
- ipconfig /flushdns
- Ipconfig /release and /renew I get this message *"This operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation"*
- netsh int ip reset all
- For machine1 in the event viewer i found this... [image]
- For the above I disabled the NetBIOS over TCP/IP
- nslookup gives right default server
- I get no such error on machine2 instead I get MSSQLSERVER SSPI handshake failed with error code ...[image]
- Restarted DNS service on the DNS on the server a few times

Comment: Just as a side note... masking 10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses is unnecessary. This is a private IP range used in thousands if not millions of networks. As long as your public IP isn't known these can't be used to compromise your network security.

Comment: Do you have DNS in your network (that is, internal DNS for server names), or are you expecting the hostname to work via NetBIOS?